# Is there a way to set "Service Addons : Automated Reboot from Monitoring" at ordering Virtual Server via API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm seeking a way to activate "Automated Reboot from Monitoring" at ordering virtual server via SoftLayer API.

In my usage, it's desireble if API provides a option to set "Automated Reboot from Monitoring" like

`client['Virtual_Guest'].createObject({
   'hostname': 'myhost',
   'domain': 'yukaary.craft.com',
   'startCpus': 1,
   'maxMemory': 1024,
   'datacenter': {"name": "tok02"},
   'privateNetworkOnlyFlag': 'true',
   'hourlyBillingFlag': 'true',
   'operatingSystemReferenceCode': 'UBUNTU_LATEST',
   'localDiskFlag': 'false',
   'serviceAddon': {'response': 'reboot'}
})`

Sorry, it's python, not PHP.

I'm searching both existing questions and sldn site, but there are no clues at moment.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do this.

Here is my sample order that is modified from exsiting server's order template: `client['Virtual_Guest'].getOrderTemplate("HOURLY", id=12345678)`.

order.json

`{
    "preTaxSetup": "0",
    "storageGroups": [],
    "postTaxRecurring": "0.111",
    "billingOrderItemId": "",
    "presetId": "",
    "prices": [
        {"id": 52123},
        {"id": 1800},
        {"id": 2202},
        {"id": 57731},
        {"id": 56679},
        {"id": 57},
        {"id": 13945},
        {"id": 273},
        {"id": 21},
        {"id": 52265},
        {"id": 905},
        {"id": 57755},
        {"id": 420},
        {"id": 418}
    ],
    "sendQuoteEmailFlag": "",
    "packageId": 46,
    "useHourlyPricing": true,
    "preTaxRecurringMonthly": "0",
    "message": "",
    "virtualGuests": [{"domain": "yukaary.craft.net", "hostname": "test"}],
    "preTaxRecurring": "0.111",
    "primaryDiskPartitionId": 1,
    "taxCompletedFlag": true,
    "isManagedOrder": 0,
    "imageTemplateId": "",
    "postTaxRecurringMonthly": "0",
    "resourceGroupTemplateId": "",
    "postTaxSetup": "0",
    "sshKeys": [{"sshKeyIds":[012345]}],
    "location": 449604,
    "stepId": "",
    "proratedInitialCharge": "0",
    "totalRecurringTax": 0,
    "paymentType": "",
    "resourceGroupId": "",
    "sourceVirtualGuestId": "",
    "bigDataOrderFlag": false,
    "extendedHardwareTesting": "",
    "preTaxRecurringHourly": "0.111",
    "monitoringAgentConfigurationTemplateGroupId": "",
    "postTaxRecurringHourly": "0.111",
    "currencyShortName": "USD",
    "proratedOrderTotal": "0",
    "serverCoreCount": 4,
    "privateCloudOrderFlag": false,
    "totalSetupTax": "0",
    "quantity": 1
}`

- it's adjusted for tok02 datacenter.

Then I ordered the virtual server by

`client['Product_Order'].placeOrder(order)`

The server was created with a option: "Monitoring Package - Premium Application" and "Automated Reboot from Monitoring".

Answer (score 0):

Using the create object you cannot configure the addoms, you need to use the placeOrder method and specify in the order the prices of the items you wish in the order.

See this documentation for more information about how to order in softlayer
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3

And may this example can help you (it is using python). you can set the options you wish to order using the names and values like the ones displayed in the portal.

```
"""
Order a new VSI.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getSshKeys
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getVlanForIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

location = "AMS01"
quantity = 1
# If you want the VSI hourly pricing
# set the value as True
useHourlyPricing = False

# The configuration of the VSI
# The values and names are the same like
# the ones displayed in the portal.
configuration = {
    "COMPUTING INSTANCE": "2 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
    "RAM": "4 GB",
    "OPERATING SYSTEM": "CentOS 7.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)",
    "FIRST DISK": "25 GB (SAN)",
    "PUBLIC BANDWIDTH": "250 GB Bandwidth",
    "UPLINK PORT SPEEDS": "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks",
    "MONITORING": "Host Ping",
    "RESPONSE": "Automated Notification",
    "Primary IP Addresses": "1 IP Address",
    "Remote Management": "Reboot / Remote Console",
    "Notification": "Email and Ticket",
    "VPN Management - Private Network": "Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account",
    "Vulnerability Assessments & Management": "Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting"
}

# Specifies the hostname and domain we want for our VSI.
# If you set quantity greater than 1 then you
# need to define one hostname/domain pair per VSI you wish to order.
virtualGuest = [
    {
        "domain": "softlayer.ibm.com",
        "hostname": "VM1",
        # The vlan configuration for the VSI if you do not wish to configure
        # the vlans just comment the lines.
        # set the any IP address which belongs to the VLAN you wish to configure in the VSI
        "backendVlanIp": "10.68.117.193",
        "frontedVLAN": "159.122.23.225"
    }
]

# The post install script to apply.
# Leave in empty if you do not wish to apply an script in the provisioning.
postInstallScript = ""

# The list of ssh keys to apply to the VSI.
# Set the label names of the ssh keys like in the portal
# Leave in empty if you do not wish to apply any ssh key.
sshKeys = ["labkey", "matt-sl-test"]


PACKAGE = 46
client = SoftLayer.Client()
orderService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']
accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']
packageService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package']
locationService = client['SoftLayer_Location']
valnService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Vlan']

try:
    location = locationService.getDatacenters(filter={"name": {"operation": location.lower()}})
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the datacenter. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(0)

try:
    pricesPackage = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE, mask="mask[categories, item]")
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the item prices. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(0)

# Getting the item prices for the order.
prices = []
for item in configuration.keys():
    for price in pricesPackage:
        added = False
        if 'categories' in price:
            for category in price['categories']:
                if category['name'].strip().upper() == item.strip().upper() and \
                   price['item']['description'].strip().upper() == configuration[item].strip().upper() and \
                   price['locationGroupId'] == "":
                    prices.append(price)
                    added = True
                    break
            if added:
                break
    if not added:
        print("There is no price for the item: " + item + "- " + configuration[item])
        exit(0)

vsis = []
for vsi in virtualGuest:
    guest = {}
    if 'domain' in vsi:
        guest['domain'] = vsi['domain']
    if 'hostname' in vsi:
        guest['hostname'] = vsi['hostname']
    if 'backendVlanIp' in vsi:
        try:
            backend = valnService.getVlanForIpAddress(vsi['backendVlanIp'])
            guest['primaryBackendNetworkComponent'] = {}
            guest['primaryBackendNetworkComponent']['networkVlan'] = backend
        except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
            print("Unable to get the backend Vlan. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    if 'frontedVLAN' in vsi:
        try:
            fronted = valnService.getVlanForIpAddress(vsi['frontedVLAN'])
            guest['primaryNetworkComponent'] = {}
            guest['primaryNetworkComponent']['networkVlan'] = fronted
        except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
            print("Unable to get the fronted Vlan. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    vsis.append(guest)


orderData = {
    "prices": prices,
    "packageId": PACKAGE,
    "location": location[0]['id'],
    'hardware': vsis,
    'useHourlyPricing': useHourlyPricing
}

if postInstallScript:
    orderData['provisionScripts'] = [postInstallScript]

if len(sshKeys) > 0:
    objectfilter = {"sshKeys": {"label": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": sshKeys}]}}}
    try:
        sshs = accountService.getSshKeys(filter=objectfilter, mask="mask[id]")
    except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        print("Unable to get the ssh keys. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    if len(sshs) > 0:
        orderData['sshKeys'] = []
        sshKeyIds = {}
        sshKeyIds['sshKeyIds'] = []
        for ssh in sshs:
            sshKeyIds['sshKeyIds'].append(ssh['id'])
        orderData['sshKeys'].append(sshKeyIds)
    else:
        print("None ssh key was found")

try:
    # When you are ready to order the VSI
    # change verifyOrder() method by placeOrder() method.
    result = orderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
    print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to create the order. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```